# Calling a function from outside of a module - arguments not passing correctly

Tags: javascript, function, module, console

So I am trying to make the console log better, when trying to log a group of objects or arrays and not just saying "object [object]", but I have problems with calling a function from a module over some arguments. For some reason, there's a difference between those two.

```
console.log(createMessage("Message: {0}", "hello")); //logs Message: hello
                                                     // (what I actually want)

specialConsole.writeLine("Message: {0}", "hello");   //logs ["Message: {0}", "hello"]
```

The first log is called from the module, the second - from outside. This is what specialConsole.writeLine returns:

```
writeLine: function () {
    console.log(createMessage(arguments));
}
```

So I am just trying to call the first log, but using specialConsole.writeLine. Sorry if my question is too stupid, but I am still a beginner. [Here is my full code in jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7djXN/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you pass two parameters to `writeLine`, `arguments` special variable will hold both the values in an array like object and you are passing it as it is to `createMessage` which assumes that you are actually passing an array and prints the data as it is.

To fix this,

```
writeLine: function () {
    console.log(createMessage.apply(null, arguments));
}
```

[`Function.prototype.apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) function passes all the elements from the array like object, as individual parameters.

Answer (score 0):

I think the difference between those two is that you pass arguments as a list, not as separate arguments. In order to correct that you would have to do this:

```
writeLine: function () {
    console.log(createMessage(arguments[0], arguments[1]);
}
```

You see the difference, however this way is not as clean, if you want pass more arguments you will need to expand all of those as well.

I would suggest expanding createMessage to accept an array instead.

Comment: Well than it will be quite more complicated, because createMessage is designed to get information from arrays and objects, when it should go through array of arrays, it will be far too complicated for me to write. I am still a beginner... Could you suggest a way to call specialConsole.writeLine over all the arguments? With some kind of for cycle or something?

Comment: @user3127242 You don't need any of that. Please check my answer.

Comment: @thefourtheye Oh, that is a much neater way to do it. I was not aware of there existing a function to do it for me.